# Build trigger in Jenkins when a specific folder changes

Tags: git, jenkins

Configure Jenkins: Where it should trigger only when a particular folder changes.

For example: 
In a file directory: Sample/Folder/ there are 3 sub folders: F1, F2, F3. 
The jenkins build should be triggered when F3 is changed and should not include F1, F2 in the build. These 3 folders should be independent in regards to the build but should be in the same file directory. 
Also is there a way we can monitor the changes in the folders?

Answer (score 3):

WIth [Jenkins pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), start your job by querying the build changeset, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265124/6309).

See if an [`when { anyOf { changeset` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50128776/6309) is enough to build if and only when the changeset includes a specific element.

See the [pipeline syntax built-in condition](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions)

> `changeset`
>
> Execute the stage if the build’s SCM changeset contains one or more files matching the given string or glob. Example: `when { changeset "**/*.js" }`

---

As noted by [PFudd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2800640/pfudd) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402861/build-trigger-in-jenkins-when-a-specific-folder-changes/56404058?noredirect=1#comment133546450_56404058):

> **WARNING**: When you create a new branch, the changeset will be empty on the first build. It's also empty if you click "Rebuild".
> See "[Jenkins Pipeline how to check for an empty changelog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70307972/6309)"
>
> The Jenkins team is aware of this, and due to the complexity of Git, they don't intend to fix it, because there is no universally-correct way to determine the right parent to compare with: see [issue JENKINS-26354](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-26354).

Reference: stackoverflow.com/questions/70307972/…

Comment: *DANGER* When you create a new branch, the changeset will be empty on the first build.  It's also empty if you click "Rebuild".  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307972/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-check-for-an-empty-changelog

Comment: The Jenkins team is aware of this, and due to the complexity of Git, they don't intend to fix it, because there is no universally-correct way to determine the right parent to compare with: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-26354